# How to add more than one foreign keys in Prisma Schema (mySQL)

Tags: mysql, prisma

I want to create three foreign keys in the Invoice Model,

1. Business_id from the business model
2. created_by which links to the User table
3. client id which links to the Users' table again

```
model Invoices {
  id                 Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  business_id        Int        @db.Int
  Businesses         Businesses @relation(fields: [business_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Cascade, onDelete: Cascade)
  created_by         Int        @db.Int
  created_by_admin   Users      @relation("created_by_admin", fields: [created_by], references: [id])
  client_id          Int
  client             Users      @relation("client", fields: [client_id], references: [id])
}
```

Comment: What issue are you facing with creating this? Your question doesn't tell us the problem you are facing with creating the foreign keys.